# is a way to quickly convert long cell character data to number matrix?

Tags: matlab

Below is the sample code that describe my issue.

```
ff= [{'1 2 3 4 5'};{'2 2 3 4 2'};{'3 2 3 4 3'};{'4 2 3 4 4'}];
YY=[];
for i=1:length(ff)
    xx=str2num(ff{i,1});
    YY=[YY;xx];
end
```

similar to the sample code my real length of ff length is very large and it is taking longer to finish the conversion. is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is going to be particularly slow since you keep expanding the size of `YY` every time through the for loop.

To optimize this, you could first convert your cell array of strings into one long string using `strjoin`. Then you can apply `str2num` to this entire string at once and reshape the result.

```
YY = reshape(str2num(strjoin(ff)), [], numel(ff)).'

%   1   2   3   4   5
%   2   2   3   4   2
%   3   2   3   4   3
%   4   2   3   4   4
```

If your version of MATLAB doesn't have `strjoin`, you can always replace it with `sprintf`

```
YY = reshape(str2num(sprintf('%s ', ff{:})), [], numel(ff)).';
```

Another option would be to convert each entry of the cell array to numbers using `cellfun` and `num2str` and then concatenate the result along the first dimension.

```
values = cellfun(@num2str, ff, 'UniformOutput', false);
YY = cat(1, values{:});
```

The first option is about twice as fast since you call `num2str` only once and the memory needed to store the temporary string created by `strjoin` is going to be less than the space required to store the same data as a numeric datatype (`double`).